# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function?

Tags: reactjs, storybook

I'm experiencing a strange React/Storybook bug.

The error I'm seeing is:

`Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.`

Here's the code that causes the error:

```
import React from 'react';
import styled from 'styled-components';

class LogoWordMark extends React.PureComponent {
  static Container = styled.div``;

  render() {
    return (
      <LogoWordMark.Container>
        mnkladjkl asdjklas djkkjlsad jklasdjklasd kl
        <a>asdad</a>
      </LogoWordMark.Container>
    );
  }
}

export default LogoWordMark;
```

What's strange is if I update one line,  with:

```
    <a onClick={this.blah}>asdad</a>
```

Then the component renders as expected. Even though `this.blah` is not defined. Any one have an idea what's going on here?

I'm using:

```
"react": "16.8.6",
"@storybook/react": "5.1.7",
```

Comment: Try to wrap the content with a `div` or a <></> (react fragment)

Comment: wrapping around the container? or inside? I tried both, no change

Comment: I meant this ```<>mnkladjkl asdjklas djkkjlsad jklasdjklasd kl
        <a>asdad</a></>```

Comment: no change... with that idea. still erroring

Comment: And what if you try to declare this ```const Container = styled.div``;``` inside the `render` and simply use ```<Container>...</Container>```?

Comment: If I make it a const then it needs to go outside of the `class LogoWordMark` which I can't do.. I can't use a const inside of the class, I get a linitng error saying const can only be used with a .ts file

Comment: no change, not sure that's any different than the current

Comment: render() {
  const Container = styled.div``; // Or let or var
  return (
    <Container>
      mnkladjkl asdjklas djkkjlsad jklasdjklasd kl
      <a>asdad</a>
    </Container>
  );
}

Comment: [This component works fine.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-nhz8r) Something else is erroring. Messing with a prop on that anchor shouldn't matter - have you tried just rebuilding with whatever build tool you're using is (in case it's just in a confused state)?

Comment: @SamVK just updated to show how I'm using the component - https://codesandbox.io/s/hmfnu -- maybe this updated example shows what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Based on the [full example you posted](https://codesandbox.io/s/hmfnu):

You're exporting `Brand` there as a default, but not [importing it as one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Importing_defaults). Change `import { Brand } from "./Brand";` to just `import Brand from "./Brand";` and [it should work.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-m9hzz)

---

This is what the error is trying to warn about at the end:

> you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Answer (score 0):

I had all my exports and imports correct so @SamVK's answer wasn't applicable to  why I was getting this error.

This error seems to occur when working with components which are static to another component. The fix I have to do is to **restart my dev server** (NextJS). (Inspiration from SamKV's comment responses to original OP)

Comment: I have the same issue, which gets resolved if i change anything in the file, but I am not using any static components. Were you able to find a root cause for why this happens ?